# How can I put an intersphinx link to an arbitrary method in the standard library documentation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, cross-reference

I am trying to use Sphinx to document a project, but I cannot figure out how to use
intersphinx.  I use this line:

```
:py:meth:`math.sin`
```

to add the link, but in the output, it shows up bold, not as a link. 
Although that line does not work, both the following do:

```
:py:meth:`dict.items`
:py:class:`zipfile.ZipFile`
```

My intersphinx_mapping value in the conf.py file is:

```
intersphinx_mapping = {'python':('http://docs.python.org/2.7', None)}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you read the documentation for [intersphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html)?

**Edit**

Got it to work using this:

```
***
TRY
***

My try
======

sin
:py:func:`math.cos`

pop
:py:meth:`dict.pop`

dict
:py:meth:`dict.items`

zipfile
:py:class:`zipfile.ZipFile`
```

Read about the constructs here [crossreference](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects)

Comment: doesn't really work for me either, found this interesting post that I'm reading right now http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.sphinx.devel/4283

Comment: I discovered that I should have used :py:func: instead of :py:meth:

Answer (score 10):

The `:py:meth:` should be `:py:func:`.  Basically, 
any valid [domain](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/domains.html) can be used.

Comment: `:py:func:` works, but it should be noted that [intersphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/intersphinx.html) must be set up first!